# How to get the Bitcoin address from the bitcoin Public key?

Tags: address, public-key, node.js

I am working in js and I need a library that helps me get an address from a public key stored in a buffer format.

Answer (score 2):

Try [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib)

The following will generate a `P2SH(P2WPKH)` address

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
let pubkey = Buffer.from('027a2c8c567a5bb7777580d31d1fd8d9910d4b1bb398570e3a36e81d7522cf828a', 'hex')
let address = bitcoin.payments.p2sh({redeem: bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({ pubkey })}).address
console.log('address: ', address)

address:  3F1JMjuxgNFuK4kBxv4JXMEdQ2yvjuz939
```